# Why do I get "sqlite[S1]: no such savepoint: svn" on TortoiseSVN commit?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Sometimes I receive the following error on a TortoiseSVN commit:

```
Commit succeeded, but other errors follow:
Error bumping revisions post-commit (details follow):
sqlite[S10]: disk I/O error
Additional errors:
sqlite[S10]: disk I/O error
Additional errors:
sqlite[S1]: no such savepoint: svn
Additional errors:
sqlite[S1]: no such savepoint: svn
Additional errors:
sqlite[S1]: no such savepoint: svn
Additional errors:
sqlite[S1]: no such savepoint: svn
```

**Why do I get these errors and how to fix this?**

Additional information:
Usually I commit files on a Samba Share via TortoiseSVN 1.8.8 Build 25755 - 64 Bit, 2014/08/10 14:44:06.
The error happens randomly. Independently of the amount of commited files.

Comment: Does it happen with any other applications? Looks worryingly like the hard drive could be on the way out, especially given that it happens randomly.

Comment: Also using the file:// protocol to access a repository on a shared drive is not recommended: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share You'd be much better setting up access to the server that hosts the share directly, via the svn://, svn+ssh:// or http:// protocols. That should work a lot better for you.

Comment: @orbey: Thank you. We thought it could be a problem with user rights on the samba share. But maybe this correlates also with the file:// protocol access. I will do some checking & testing with the server share protocols and update the question here afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you lack write permissions on the drive.

I just had the same error. We are using svn on network drives that are attached via the tool: VHD Attach. I was attaching the network drive in "read only" mode by accident which led to the same error message:

```
sqlite[S1]: no such savepoint: svn
```

So I detached it again and attached the drive normally. ( -> not via the dropdown, but the button itself.) Now it's working again as expected.

I hope this helps anybody who stumbles over this error message in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error. In my case, the disk was completely full. After deleting some files, it worked like a charm.